# How to display fragment on full screen?

Tags: android, fragment, fullscreen

If I am using parent layout as container.. fragment is not visible
and if i use child layout as container.. its displaying fragment in wrap_content, not in full screen.. even my fragment layout height is `match_parent`

[image]

How to open fragment in full screen?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container">  <!-- this id identifies fragment container -->

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/innerContainer"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/container">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.thevisionspark.jobsite.AppliedUsers">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/innerContainer">

        <TextView
            style="@style/headings"
            android:text="Applied Users"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

fragment loading code

```
FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    AppliedUsers frag = new AppliedUsers();
                    frag.setArguments(bundle);

                    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() == null)
                        fm.add(R.id.container, frag).commit();

                    else fm.replace(R.id.container, frag).commit();
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: also what is @style/innerContainer ?

Comment: @style/innerContainer this is only style what set padding with match_parent height and width

Comment: ok , can you add a screenshot of the result ? it's hard to guess without it

Answer (score 2):

You can use a button to launch the fragment, inside that button's click listener set visibility of you Activity's widgets to GONE like this.

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yourWidget.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            anotherWidget.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            Fragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.your_activity_layout, YourFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Now Create an abstract method inside a callback interface

```
public interface MakeVisible {

void makeVisible();
}
```

now inside your activity

```
public class Activity extends FragmentActivity implements MakeVisible{
@Override
public void makeVisible() {
   yourWidget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anotherWidget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}
```

Finally do this in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    MakeVisible makeVisible = (MakeVisible) getActivity();
    makeVisible.makeVisible();
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only working solution i found so far for my problem, just a note: i changed the visibility of the parent activity inside the onCreate() and the onDetach() methods of the frame and it works as intended

Answer (score 0):

Follow it -

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its main layout. Here **FrameLayout** with id **flMain** is the container for fragment.  And following code is for the fragment -

```java
public class CustomFragment  extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View customeFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);


        return customeFragment;
    }
}
```

And following code is for **FragmentTransaction** .

```java
CustomeFragment customeFragment = new CustomeFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()  .replace(R.id.flMain, customeFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

If you face any problem then put a comment on here.

Comment: i added screenshot kindly check it

Comment: pleased provide full code of container layout. I mean main screen which you attached as screenshot.

Comment: You cant use Activity and Fragment in same activity. Fragment can be used as a sub-activity of activity. You can use two fragments in one activity. So make it fragment which you marked as activity on screenshot  or use CardView.

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity a FrameLayout

The first child will stay the same with the layout you want to hide later ,

The second child will be this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container">  <!-- this id identifies fragment container -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The inner child of it(with the background="@drawable/container") should be set inside the fragment,

Try it.